# Python: how to compute covariance matrix and export data like a map structure

Tags: python, matrix, dictionary, covariance

The input is three arrays: Row_Index, Column_Index, Weight.  Imagine a two dimensional array. It is very sparse and only few entries are non-zero. Its like that "Row_Index" and "Column_Index" contains the co-ordinates of the non-zero values and "Weight" contains the actual value

```
Row_Index = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5] (number of rows = 5);
Column_Index = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35, 45, 20, 30, 10, 55]  (number of columns = 55);
Weight = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

How can I compute a 55*55 Covariance Matrix based on the input data in Python. And export the value in terms of another three columns container the feature, its co-feature and the correlation coefficient? eg {1,1,1}, {1,2,0} {1,10, -0.5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used numpy? It's a great math package for python, with statistics and matrix support built-in.

Example from numpy [website](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]).T

>>> np.cov(x)
array([[ 1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.]])
```